# Is it safe to call Thread.getState() immediately after Thread.start()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is the following method thread safe, or can it throw `IllegalThreadStateException`?

```
class MyClass {
    private final Thread t = ...;
    public synchronized void startTheThreadIfNew() {
        if (t.getState().equals(Thread.State.NEW)) {
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Is `Thread.start()` guaranteed to return after changing the state?

Comment: No. from the javadoc: "getState() Returns the state of this thread. This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control." And it is not synchronized

Comment: This looks like the beginnings of poor design. I'd advice strongly against continuing from here.

Answer (score 0):

From below demo, it gives a clue that ***getState()*** is not safe because is not ***thread-safe***.

```
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    semaphore.acquire();

    Thread AThread = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i =0; ;) {
            try {
                semaphore.tryAcquire(10*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("timeout");
        }
    });
    AThread.setName("athread");
    AThread.start();

    for (int i= 0; ;) {
        if (AThread.getState().equals(Thread.State.RUNNABLE)) {
            System.out.println("getThread state:" + " " + AThread.getState());
        }
    }
```

As you might see, the console will output something like (because not thread-safe)

```
getThread state: RUNNABLE
getThread state: RUNNABLE
getThread state: RUNNABLE
getThread state: TIMED_WAITING
timeout
```